# asp Menu control not floating properly

Tags: asp.net, css, menu, css-float

I'm trying to do this on my header:

```
Link | Link | Link                                               LoginStatus
```

But the Menu Control just won't float. What it does is like this:

```
Link | Link | Link
LoginStatus
```

I've tried floating it left but still doesn't work.

```
<div class="menucontainer">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" Style="float:left">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Generate Report" 
                            Value="Generate Report"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem Selectable="False" Text="|"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Download.aspx" Text="Mass Export" 
                            Value="Mass Export"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="|"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Home.aspx" Text="Login" 
                            Value="Login"></asp:MenuItem>
                    </Items>
                    <StaticMenuItemStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" 
                        BorderWidth="1px" />
                </asp:Menu>
                <div style="float:left">asdaddas</div>
          </div>
```

CSS

```
div.menucontainer
{
    background-color:#465C71;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #465c71;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    width:100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 1px 1px;  /*FF1+ */
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 1px 1px; /* Saf3-4, iOS 1+, Android 1.5+ */
    border-radius: 4px 4px 1px 1px;/*  Opera 10.5, IE9, Saf5, Chrome, FF4 */
    clear:both;
}

div.menu
{
    padding: 4px 0px 0px 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    border-right: 20px solid red;
    clear:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just wrap your Menu Tag in a div and float that div.

```
<div id="OuterDiv">
  <div style="float: right;">
    <asp:Menu>
    </asp:Menu>
  </div>
  ....
</div>
```

Comment: In your example above, you do not have a dedicated Div wrapped around your menu. There is a very important distinction

Comment: How did you get this to work? A horizontal asp menu inserts an auto clear div after the menu (as you mentioned in a comment previously). I cannot get this to work

Answer (score 0):

If you have the links working correctly with `float:left`, why not use `float:right` on your LoginStatus button (it's in its own `div`, from what I can tell).

Comment: i've tried that already and it still gets another line below. it seems like the menu control has an auto clear :/