# ASP Menu float property is not working

Tags: html, css, asp.net, css-float, aspmenu

I have an asp menu, I want to float it to left so the element after it can come to its right side (beside) it. I've set a `CssClass` for the `Menu` and added `float: left`to it, but it is not working. I've even changed the `float:left` to `float:right` to see if it will work or not, but nothing worked.

Here is my code:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="navbar">


        /*some code*/

     </div>

    <div class="middle"> 



    <asp:Menu ID="MenuRec" runat="server" CssClass="recFriends">
         <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="People you may know:" Selectable="false" Enabled="false"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="<br/>" Selectable="false" Enabled="false"></asp:MenuItem>

        </Items>

         <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem Text=" Item1"  Selectable="false"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text=" Item2"  Selectable="false"></asp:MenuItem>
             <asp:MenuItem Text=" Item3" Selectable="false"></asp:MenuItem>
        </Items>
    </asp:Menu>



          <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            <!--here goes the customized content--> 
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

  </div>
     <div class="footer">

    </div>
</div>
</form>

</body>
```

My CSS:

```
.recFriends {

    float:left;  
    padding-top:1em;
    color:#003366; 
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:italic; 
}
```

controls inside the `ContentPlaceHolder` (which will be in a page that inherits from this master page) must come to the right of the menu, but these are coming below it instead.

I've searched a lot, but nothing worked, I've even checked the solutions available here:

[CssClass is not working for my asp menu - all code attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574306/cssclass-is-not-working-for-my-asp-menu-all-code-attached)

[asp Menu control not floating properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039769/asp-menu-control-not-floating-properly)

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: did you try with `!important`?

Comment: have you tried adding float: left to your contentPlaceHolder too?

Comment: @Lal yes, I've written !important just beside the float property, but it didn't work. Can you please tell me what solutions may solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle or something like that..

Comment: @SheppardDigital contentPlaceHolder doesn't take a CssClass property, nor the content control which inherits it has a CssClass, so how can I add it? Thanks.

Comment: You could maybe add a div around your content placeholder and give it a class? <div class="contentArea"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder></div>

Comment: @Lal, can you please clarify what do you mean by fiddle?

Comment: put your codes in jsfiddle.net..and share the link with us..so that we can debug it..

Comment: @SheppardDigital yes, I've tried that, but it didn't work, this solution was provided in another question, but it didn't work in my case.

Comment: @Lal, thanks I appreciate this, but unfortunately I can't share the entire code, because it's confidential. I can only share a small portion like the one provided in the question. Is there any other solution?

Comment: yes thats it,..just add the relevant code to reproduce this issue..please dont add the full code.

Comment: @SheppardDigital I added a dive around the ContentPlaceHolder and give it a class with float left, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Lal, thanks, I added this portion to fiddle.net, clicked run, but there was no result shown.

Comment: It wont run asp..you will have to paste the html..

Comment: @Lal So shall I remove the asp menu tag? I removed that and place it with h1 for testing purposes, the result is that the first h1 comes bellow the second one! the float was not considered in the result.

Comment: press the save button and please share the link with us..

Comment: @Lal here is the link, http://jsfiddle.net/6f1bpLc5/

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/6f1bpLc5/1/) what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Lal, yes but I applied the same concept you provided, once for the contentplaceholder and once for the content in the child page, but it didn't work, it's ok, I will try to add some space at the top margin of the menu so it can be at the same level of the other control. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Good...:) carry on...just to remind you, please use the `inspect element` utility of your browser to find the computed styles and check if any margins or paddings are being applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your menu in a div and close the div before the content place holder. Move your CSS class from the menu to the container div.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="recFriends">
            <asp:Menu ID="MenuRec" runat="server">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="People you may know:" Selectable="false" Enabled="false"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="<br/>" Selectable="false" Enabled="false"></asp:MenuItem>

                </Items>

                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text=" Item1" Selectable="false"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text=" Item2" Selectable="false"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text=" Item3" Selectable="false"></asp:MenuItem>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
        </div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            <!--here goes the customized content-->
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

CSS

```
 .recFriends {
        float: left;
        padding-top: 1em;
        color: #003366;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: italic;
        width: 20%;
        padding-left: 2em;
    }
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: thanks, what is #MainContent_MenuRec a? and where shall I place it? Can you please elaborate more? Do you mean I should have the CSS like this, .recFriends a?

Comment: The #MainContent_MenuRec A is the default css class for the asp menu. You can override the CSS as described in the answer. I've also attached a sample.

Comment: thank you for this clear answer, but this is not what I want to do. I used the code you provided and it didn't work. I don't want to place the items to the right of the menu, I want to place the ContentPlaceHolder to the right of the menu, any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that. Do you need the content of pages to be placed to the right of the Menu? BTW. if you are adding your style in a master page the class should be "MenuRec a" instead of  MainContent_MenuRec a

Comment: In the code in the question, there is a ContentPlaceHolder asp tag, this tag will be associated to an asp content tag in the page that will inherit from this master page. I want whatever contents in the content tag in the child page to be to the right of the menu in the master page. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Would you check the answer again. Is the last image is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Moe, I tried your method, it worked very well! Thanks a lot.